# Databases - Do tables in a database have to contain all global instances or can they be specific to a certain ID

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to model a database for facebook users. For my User table I have {account_name, account_id, ..., password} as variables. I'm trying to create a table for friends of that user, such as a Friendlist or Contacts table, but I'm wondering would the contacts table have to have a list of all the possible friendships (i.e. {user_id, friend_id, friends_since,...} ) or is it possible to have the contact table specific to a certain user_id (so {contact_id, friends_since, no_of_mutual_contacts, etc..}).

This is probably just the object orientated part of my brain coming into action, but say for example if we were using a Cinema database. There were 5 cinemas and each had 5 screens, CINEMA is a table and SCREEN is a table. Would the SCREEN table have 25 instances of data or is there some way that the SCREEN table would only contain the 5 screens corresponding to a specific CINEMA.

This comes back to my original question, would the Contacts table have to be a global table containing all friendships, or does the Contacts table only return the contacts specific to the user_id.

For some reason when I'm looking at the relational chart of the database I see the connections ressembling a somewhat object like structure where the links are just denoted members like user.Contacts or user.Events.

Comment: Please don't confuse OOP with data modeling. OOP is for decomposing complex systems into interactive networks of stateful services. Data modeling is for decomposing complex knowledge into sets of simple facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a table in a relational database will record all facts of a given type, e.g. `user <user_id> is friends with user <friend_id> since <friends_since>`.

You can create views for given users if required, or just specify a user_id in your queries, to get the subset of rows applicable to a specific user.

Creating a physical table specific to certain users would create difficulties if you wanted to get all the rows for a certain `friend_id`.